# A heading on a paper

Tags: academic-writing, punctuation, collaboration, authorship

When you are doing a research paper or a writing and you have two people doing it, do you put a comma before the and in something like... By Arielle, and Bella?

Comment: Do you mean in the attribution or within the article itself? If I was saying who wrote it I would be using surnames as well. If it was within the article I wouldn't use a comma.

Answer (score 2):

No comma is needed in lists of two things: "By Arielle and Bella." And "I have a dog and a cat."

If the list has more than two items, then add commas: "Written by Arielle, Bella, and Clara." (Some styles don't add that last comma, the "Oxford comma.")

Comment: Comma never precedes "and" ...it's redundant.

Comment: @Tapper7, whether to use the Oxford comma depends on the style guide you're using. (Unless my employer uses something different, I use Chicago Manual of Style, which specifies usage of the comma.) I like using it since it provides clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If you cite a source following a style guide like the APA Manual, you may encounter something like the following:

> Mohnkern, K., & Maiuro, A. (2016). A heading on a paper. ...

Here, the comma before the "&" is the closing comma after the parenthesized abbreviated first name ("K.").

Maybe you saw something like this and thought it applied to all lists of names?

Comment: I'd read that paper.